# 'Are you really want to quit ?' vs 'Do you really want to quit ?'

Tags: differences, subcontinental-english

First things first , English is not my Native Language / Mother tongue .

I am a game developer . So when a player presses exit button a message pops up and asks whether they want to quit the game or not .

So which is the better way to ask , 'Are you really want to quit this game ?' -- OR -- 'Do you really want to quit this game ?' .

Hope you will help me to figure it out .

Regards ,
NB :)

Comment: "Are you really wanting..." or "Do you really want..."  NOT *"Are you really want..." NOR *"Do you really wanting..."

Comment: Check out our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are you really want to quit

Only correct if it means: is your name/title "want to quit"?

Probably not what you mean.

> Are you really wanting to quit

Technically correct but not idiomatic.  It's rather awkward.  But the tenses agree.

> Do you really want to quit?

Is idiomatic and natural.